TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'insertBefore') when adding vuetify to existing vue 3 app

I'm trying to add vuetify to an existing vue3 project but it triggers this error in some views:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'insertBefore')

Removing <v-app> and <v-main> from the main App.vue file is enough to make it disappear. Any idea why it happens or how to fix it? I didn't do anything else apart from adding vuetify to the project, both following these istructions to add it to an existing project and also adding vuetify to my project the same way as yarn create vuetify (the build system is a bit different). In both cases I get the same error, which I don't get in other apps.

Please, provide a way to reproduce, this could be anything. This is generic error that can occur with v-if or something else DOM-related

That's the problem: I have no idea how to reproduce it. Could you please point me in the right direction? What should I look for in particular about v-if? Why might it happen only with <v-app/main>?

This depends on the implementation of vuetify or your own components. The error means that DOM element that is expected to exist doesn't exist. So anything in a component can cause this. A repo or stackblitz/codesandbox with an app as simple as needed to reproduce the problem would be fine. " also replicating what yarn create vuetify does" - I can confirm this doesn't happen with this template alone with no other actions, it would be surprising if a big project like vuetify would have this problem and nobody reported it.

Sorry I was not clear: I cannot reproduce it in a brand new yarn create vuetify project. What I've tried to do was replicating the build system of a yarn create vuetify project into my existing customer's project (it's quite different from the instructions on their page). I've edited the question to specify that.
What I don't really understand is how a DOM element that is expected to exist can or cannot exist depending on the presence of a <v-app/main> tag: the error doesn't happen without <v-app/main>
I've tried to pinpoint it to something specific but there are multiple potential culprits.

Doing the following from a parent component onMounted(() => { selected.value = 5 }) where the template is  is enough to trigger the issue. The result is the same either if not-existing is an existing or not existing prop of BrokenChild.

The presence of v-app and v-main results in a complex issue that can affect underlying vuetify components, and these components can cause the error themselves depending on what happens inside of them. This needs to be debugged

I started tearing the whole application down piece by piece and it turned out to be triggered by a dynamic component. Still no idea why, I'll keep you updated.

Does it use dynamic import? Because v-app/main uses suspense, this affects async components

It uses defineAsyncComponent. The weird thing is that the dynamic component per se isn't an issue: it causes the error only if it's rendered inside the default slot of a  (it's really nothing more than an icon). Even weirder if I render it inside a  everything works!

I think I can finally provide a repro, but you will have to be a little bit patient for that. Thanks
